# Rxjs recursion with bindcallback

Tags: javascript, recursion, redux, rxjs

Long story short: I'm trying to recursively get paginated data from an API call that I've wrapped in a `bindCallback`, but the recursion isn't working.

Details:

I'm calling the `request` function in the [Pinterest Javascript SDK](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/js/) to grab pins from a board. The API call itself takes both parameters and a callback. The response returned from that call contains the (paged) data, as well as a boolean, `hasNext`, and a recursive call `next()` to grab the next pagination of data. The Pinterest API says that `next()` "will recursively go to this same callback."

```
const Pinterest = {
    pins: (boardName, callback) => {
        var params = {
            fields: "id, note, link, image",
            limit: 100
        };
        var boardId = `test`;
        PDK.request(`${boardId}/pins/`, params, callback);
    }
};

type BoardPinsResponse = {
    data: Array<Pin>;
    hasNext?: boolean;
    page?: {
        cursor: string;
        next: string; 
        // This is the straight URL that would grab the next set of data
    };
    next: () => BoardPinsResponse 
    // This is a helper function that is supposed to grab the data from the "next" URL above
};
```

I'm using Redux epics in my React app to handle these calls, so everything is in Rxjs Observables. I've solved getting the first part of the data, as I just wrap the API call in RxJS's `bindCallback` to bring out the callback.

```
const pinsObservable = bindCallback(Pinterest.pins);

const fetchPinsEpic = (action$, _) =>
    action$.pipe(
        filter(isActionOf(fetchPinsAsync.request)),
        mergeMap(action =>
            pinsObservable(action.payload).pipe(
                expand(response => response.hasNext ? of(response.next()) : empty()),

                // ^ this call doesn't seem to be working

                map(response => {
                    return fetchPinsAsync.success({
                        month: action.payload,
                        pins: response.data
                    });
                }),
                catchError((message: string) =>
                    of(fetchPinsAsync.failure(message))
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

The problem now becomes how to call the recursive link returned by the API. Calling it just inside the `map` function isn't doing anything, as I believe the `bindCallback` only allows a single call. I would assume that I could use the `expand` operator to recursively make this happen until the `hasNext` returns false, but I cannot seem to get the call to push through the data. I can see it go to the correct branch once to fetch more data, but then never see the recursion happen.

Is there something I have to put after the `expand` to catch the data? Does putting the `expand` inside the `bindCallback` not work?

Edit: I've since realized that the API response contains TWO "next" properties. I've updated my code accordingly, but am still stuck.

Comment: Try replacing `pinsObservable(action.payload)` with `bindCallback(Pinterest.pins)(action.payload)` - see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1401

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to help -- this results in the same issue where it's entering the recursive part of the branch but then seems to disappear

Comment: It seems weird for the API response's  `next` method to be synchronous. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: So two things: 1) I realized that the response contains TWO "next" parameters, one being the straight URL and one the helper function, and I was using the wrong one. But yes, it does appear to be synchronous as far as I can tell -- the URL contains all of the parameters plus a "cursor" that I'm assuming indicates the id of the last piece of data that it picked up.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do this within the observable itself:

```
mergeMap(action =>
  new Observable(subscriber => {
    var pins = [];
    PDK.request('/boards/<board_id>/pins/', function (response) { // Make sure to change the board_id
      if (!response || response.error) {
        subscriber.next(fetchPinsAsync.failure(response.error));
        subscriber.complete();
        return;
      }
      pins = pins.concat(response.data);
      if (response.hasNext) {
        response.next(); // this will recursively go to this same callback
        return;
      }
      subscriber.next(fetchPinsAsync.success({
          month: action.payload,
          pins: pins
      }));
      subscriber.complete();      
    });
  })
)
```